# how many jdbc connections needed by spring batch framework

Tags: spring-batch

Does anyone know how many connections being used by spring batch framework when it tries to store certain data in Batch_* tables?

We are trying to estimates connection pool size where we know how many connection will be needed for our domain db but we have batch schema in diff db and want to set the pool size properly since we are getting error like cannot object db connection from the pool

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you are writing to database, single thread or multiResourceItemWriter, I had come across similar issues when I had multiple Item Resource reading in parallel from file and writing into to database in parallel. in this case if connection pool size is less than thread pool you will get the above error.